# Not able to map data from Swift to Objective-C model

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

I am trying to call one api from Swift and i need to create one model data from Objective-C. But not able to map the data.

Here is my response :

```
let  busResponses = [
    "ResponseStatus": [
        "ResponseCode": "SUCCESS",
        "ResponseMessage": "SUCCESS",
    ],
    "ResponseData": [
        "BusNo": "119",
        "bookingId": "22654"    
    ]
]
```

My swift class where i am calling the api :

When i call my api in my completion handler i have written like :

```
request.load(urlCache: nil) { [weak self] (apiResponse: [String:Any]?, error: Error?) ->Void in

}
```

apiResponse is my response what i am getting from my api call.Then i am mapping to my BusResponse model from objective class.

```
let response: BusResponse? = BusResponse(value: piResponses)
completion(response, nil)
```

My objective c model class :

**BusResponse.h :**

```
@interface ResponseData : BaseRealmUnique
@property NSString * BusNo;
@property NSString * bookingId;
@end

@interface ResponseStatus : BaseRealmUnique
@property NSString * ResponseCode;
@property NSString * ResponseMessage;
@end

@interface CheckInData : BaseRealmObject

@property ResponseStatus * ResponseStatus;
@property ResponseData * ResponseData;

@end

@interface CheckInResponse : BaseResponseBase

@property CheckInData  *checkInData;
+ (NSURL *)url;

@end
```

BusResponse.m :

```
#import "BusResponse.h"

@implementation CheckInData

@end


@implementation ResponseData
@end


@implementation ResponseStatus
@end


@implementation CheckInResponse

+ (NSURL *)url
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

My main doubt is that initially after calling api, the response i am handling as `apiResponse: [String:Any]?`. But my response data is not same.

So i tried with hardcode response and pass to `let response: BusResponse? = BusResponse(value: piResponses)`. Here also , when i print my response its nil. I want my `busNo , BookingId` string value , with the response code, response message .

What i am doing wrong. Any help would be great.

Comment: You don't have a method named `-(id)initWithValue:(NSDictionary *)dic`? in `BusResponse`?

Comment: Not sure, but same manner we are using for other model also

Comment: @Larme.  Is my type is right ?

Comment: @Larme. Any help on this?

Comment: repair CamelCaseNameScheme (capitalized variable names) in CheckInDatas, ResponseData, ResponseStatus properties. Reading from your class names, BusResponse and CheckInData:BaseResponseBase are unrelated. And as @Larme pointed out (swift)`BusResponse(value:...)` will go looking for a objC method `-(id)initWithValue:(NSDictionary*)dict;` which is in a not existent class BusResponse as mentioned above.

Comment: There might be present in the super class, I suspect the use of Realm. Since I don't use it, I don't know what's happening there, there might be some mapping done under the hood.

Comment: indeed. but the naming of the header and implementation file suggests it was meant to define BusResponse.